# llvm-as error converting IR to Bitcode

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I tried to convert an LLVM-IR file to bitcode with llvm-as, but it returned an error:

```
llvm-as-3.4: test.ll:70:9: error: 
expected type declare "__mtest__" void @__Init()
```

The function `void @__Init()` is from my code, but there is no option to add an include path. Does anyone have some advice for solving this problem?

Comment: can you provide a code sample?

Comment: Thanks! I have solved it now. I have to delete "__mtest__" first first.